# screen not displaying with Startech hdmi to usb adapter

Tags: drivers, sound, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I bought a startech hdmi to usb adapter a few weeks ago.

I've installed the driver for my ubuntu, display was doing fine.

However, a few weeks later, the screen is now, not displaying any images.

Funny part is that the star tech adapter is recognized when I plugged it in and the strange thing is that the sound channel is using the startech adapter.

Not sure, what is wrong.

When I type `xrandr`, no additional HDMI plugin is seen.

This is the [plugin](https://www.itproshop.com/startech-com-adaptateur-video-multi-ecrans-usb-3-0-vers-hdmi-pour-mac-pc/p2418821?gclid=Cj0KCQjw8IaGBhCHARIsAGIRRYrBQ7BF7t9iMDD9AI3wjbYvy9o2nRJKq-YjQBUmX0HQV2nBKObIbSsaAuwcEALw_wcB) I'm talking about.

I've done all the required updates through `apt update`.

If you have any ideas, I'm more than glad to hear them.

PS: I was thinking to have a look at the BIOS but not sure, what I should be looking for.

Update

This is my config after a `lsusb -t` without the connector

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=asix, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
```

This is my config after a `lsusb -t` **with** the connector

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 1, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 9, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=asix, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
```

Comment: Test the adapter on another PC and/or with another monitor. PS HDMI is a video and audio signal

Comment: @paladin tried that, on two pcs, one with linux and one with windows. Both are displaying the third screen. I was thinking that it may have something to do with the hard drive and the OS. Maybe replace the current OS with Windows.

Comment: Maybe your USB 3.0 port doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @paladin when I plug it the connector, it does recognize it as the sound is pass through that usb port. When I put a usb stick, it does recognize the stick and show me the content of it.

Comment: Is this some kind of USB stick where the driver software is also stored on it? Because this is probably the reason for your problem. USB devices have different operating modi, and maybe your OS is recognizing your USB stick only as a mass storage device + some kind of USB soundcard. It's possible to manual change the USB operating modi, but I can't remember where to do.

Comment: @paladin maybe. If you have any ideas, I'm glad to hear them.

Comment: @paladin pls have a look at my update.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of the computer, as well as which version of Ubuntu you're using? This will make it easier to do some digging to see if a recent update has b0rk3n the functionality 

Comment: @paladin from the link above, it looks like it is using usb 2 (via usb-a port). I didnt think that hdmi via usb 2 was a thing. I thought that was one of the main selling points of usb-c cables. Initially, I thought that was the issue, but it looks as if usb-a /usb 2.0 standard is the intentional method of data exchange?

Comment: OP, have you tried reinstalling the drivers via --reinstall? Dependencies couldve been deleted by another install, or something similar. Seems like a good first step (or worth marking it off the 'could be...' list.)

Comment: Something seems fishy with the product you linked. It says "via usb 3.0" in the comments, yet shows a female usb-a input in the pic. usb-a only has 4 channels via 4 inner wires, and so cannot work with usb 3 data transfer applications (and, I thought, hdmi.) What type of usb cord does your device take?

Answer (score 0):

As you say the adapter works fine on other computers the adapter appears fine.  Being a DisplayLink adapter it requires drivers for video to appear.  I believe the reason you get audio is that the adapter has one chip for audio and a different one for video, and the driver for audio is working but the video driver is not.  Did you attempt any repairs of the drivers?

I'd check the HDMI cable for damage if you didn't rule that out already.  Make sure both ends are secure in their sockets.

If the drivers are fine, the cable is fine, and the adapter is fine, then perhaps there was some damage to the USB port.  Do other USB 3.0 devices work fine in that port?  Could there be bent pins?

Comment: both usb ports give me the same results.